# How to control QML UI with PySide?

Tags: python, qml, pyside

I try to create QML-PYSIDE calculator. However I couldnt find any example like that. I also checked pyside wiki but couldn't understand how to run QML-PySide together. 
   For example I would like to run addition app with QML-PySİde.( a+b=c). I can control addition app GUI (sumui.ui) created by QtDesigner with Python (converted by PySideTools). But I can't control addition app QML (inputtext, button ) with Python.
   I'm new to python-qt. So I typed pyside-qtdesigner and qml GUI for understanding relitionship between PySide-QtWidgets and PySide-QML UI. (sorry for my bad English)

PySide addition app:

Picture of app: http://postimg.org/image/envp8jgg9/

addition.py:

```
# addition.py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from sumui import Ui_Form
import sys

def derece(degrees):
    return degrees*((2*pi)/400)
class hesap(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
      QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

      self.ui = Ui_Form()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)

      # Validations
      tempValidator = QtGui.QDoubleValidator()
      tempValidator.setNotation(QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
      self.ui.a.setValidator(tempValidator)
      self.ui.b.setValidator(tempValidator)
      self.setupConnections()

    def topla(self):
        a1 = float(self.ui.a.text())
        b1 = float(self.ui.b.text())
        c1 = a1 + b1
        cc1 = str(c1)
        self.ui.c.setText(str(cc1))



    def setupConnections(self):
        self.connect(self.ui.sum, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
          self.topla)
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = hesap()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QML GUI: http://postimg.org/image/pocxfcf19/
addition.qml:

```
import QtQuick 1.1
Rectangle {
    id:r
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Column{
        width: r.width*0.8
        height: r.height*0.8
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Row{
            id:ro
            spacing:10
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: ro.parent
                font.bold: true
                text: "a"
            }
            TextInput {
                id: a
                width: r.width*3/4
                height: 20
                selectionColor: "#2f8bc5"
                fillColor: "lightgray"
                font.bold: true
            }
        }
        Row{
            spacing:10
        Text {
            text: "b"
            font.bold: true
        }
        TextInput {
            id: b
            width: r.width*3/4
            height: 20
            fillColor: "lightgray"
            font.bold: true
        }
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: calculate
            width: r.width
            height: 30
            color: "#8a0800"
            //x:b.width*0.2
            Text{
                anchors.centerIn: calculate
                font.bold: true
                text:"calculate";color:"white"}
                gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#8a0800"
                }
                GradientStop {
                    position: 1
                    color: "#330009"
                }
            }
        }

        Row{
            spacing:10
        Text {
            text: "c"
            font.bold: true
        }
        TextInput {
            id: c
            font.bold: true
            width: r.width*3/4
            height: 20
            fillColor: "lightgray"
            selectionColor: "#2f8bc5"
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }
        }
    }
}
```

How to run QML addition UI with PySide? Or is there any example like PySide-QML calculator?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So You want to show result from pyside method on QML GUI?
Now You have two UI: Qt Widget and QML. I think you want to control QML gui from pyside app (only QML UI).
First You have to load qml file from pyside (http://qt-project.org/wiki/Hello-World-in-PySide-and-QtQuick). Second thing are SIGNALS and SLOTS (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36782-SOLVED-qml-signal-with-c-slot).
Your calculate button should emit signal with a and b variables to pyside layer, and pyside layer should have slot for that signal and that slot will calculate both variables and emits signal with result to qml slot and qml slot will show that result in qml ui.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I meant that. I can run single QML with python. But I didn't try to run multiple QML files with python.  I will try to run multi - QML. This is a good idea to research about c++ -Qt examples, I don't know anything about c++. But I will research similar examples between c++ and PyQt. Then I will compare them for controlling signals and slots. As a result PySide and C++ use same API with Qt. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an interface that updates the score when you click on a button. It could probably be designed without much interaction with python, but in many cases we want the signal to go down to Python no matter how genius the interface layer can be.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore,QtDeclarative, QtGui

class QtScoreInterface(QtCore.QObject ):

    signaller_score_a = QtCore.Signal(str)
    signaller_score_b = QtCore.Signal(str)


    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.score_a = 0
        self.score_b = 0

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def aScored(self):
        print ("A_scored");
        self.score_a += 1
        self.updateScore()


    @QtCore.Slot()
    def bScored(self):
        print ("B_scored");
        self.score_b += 1
        self.updateScore()


    @QtCore.Slot()
    def startMatch(self):
        print ("Game start stopped");


    def updateScore(self):
        self.signaller_score_a.emit(str(self.score_a))
        self.signaller_score_b.emit(str(self.score_b))


class MainView( QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super( MainView, self ).__init__( parent )
        self.setWindowTitle( "ScoreKeeper" )
        self.setSource( QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile( './main.qml' ) )
        self.setResizeMode( QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView.SizeRootObjectToView )


qApplication = QtGui.QApplication( sys.argv )
window = MainView()
window.show();

qcontext = window.rootContext() 
interface = QtScoreInterface()
qcontext.setContextProperty("qScoreInterface",interface)

interface.signaller_score_a.connect(window.rootObject().updateScoreA)
interface.signaller_score_b.connect(window.rootObject().updateScoreB)

sys.exit( qApplication.exec_() )
```

Here is the QML file (main.qml):

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle1
    width: 480
    height: 272



    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop {
            id: gradientStop1
            position: 0
            color: "#ffffff"
        }

        GradientStop {
            position: 1
            color: "#abc09f"
        }
    }

    function updateScoreA(string ) {
        score_a.text = string
    }

    function updateScoreB(string ) {
        score_b.text = string
    }

    Text {
        id: score_a
        x: 45
        y: 8
        width: 131
        height: 48
        text: qsTr("Text")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    Text {
        id: score_b
        x: 303
        y: 8
        width: 131
        height: 48
        text: qsTr("Text")
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
        font.pixelSize: 12




    }

    Text {
        id: dash
        x: 232
        y: 5
        text: qsTr("-")
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 47
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: a_scored
        x: 303
        y: 200
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: team_a
        x: 45
        y: 218
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10

        TextInput {
            id: team_a_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("A")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: team_a_score_ma
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.aScored()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: team_b
        x: 307
        y: 218
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10
        TextInput {
            id: team_b_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("B")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: team_b_score_ma
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.bScored()
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: startstopgame
        x: 177
        y: 113
        width: 127
        height: 46
        color: "#4e3a3a"
        radius: 10
        TextInput {
            id: startstopgame_txt
            x: 24
            y: 13
            width: 80
            height: 20
            text: qsTr("Start Game")
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 12
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: startstopgame_ma
            x: 1
            y: 0
            width: 126
            height: 46
            onClicked: {
                qScoreInterface.startMatch()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good example for understanding control QML by Python.

Comment: There is a solution like that: http://postimg.org/image/ipd0c4vun/                                                      testqml.qml: http://pastebin.com/e8faShwL                                     main.py: http://pastebin.com/auCpncS2 Just problem is it cannot calculate with any buton. It works with enter key. I would like to control QML object using "QObjectName". Because there are many parameters for calculation.